# Pose mode mesh distortion

Tags: mesh, rigging, armature

I am trying to make an animated human in Blender.
First, I imported a human mesh. Then, with the Rigify Addon, I added a skeleton and adapted it to the mesh. No problems so far, but, when I try to do the *Skinning*, the mesh becomes very large (see picture 1). Also, when I move bones of the skeleton rig in *Pose mode*, I can see distortions on the mesh (picture 2).

[image: imported human mesh]

[image: human mesh and armature in wrong place]

Comment: It is quite common to have the armature within the mesh.  So many readers may consider your placement of armature and mesh very inefficient.  It is probably clear to you that most humans do not have a knee that low on the leg. It is difficult to help with your current arrangement. You many need a tutorial series.  Here is one https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lY6KPrc4uMw&list=PLda3VoSoc_TR7X7wfblBGiRz-bvhKpGkS   .  This one lightly discuss armature placement  .... https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GvG39bGEsKI&list=PLda3VoSoc_TR7X7wfblBGiRz-bvhKpGkS&index=35

Comment: Thanks but i dont think it's a placement of armature problem. On the second image, we can see 2 rotation points on the lower leg of the mesh, but on the armature there is just one !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the armature has to be "in the mesh".

Here the left mesh and the armature are in a fitting position.
On the right, the mesh copy is offset and so the bone angles are creating distortions.

[image]

Comment: And how can i check that ?

Comment: move the armature (keep the pose like in your picture) in object mode and look how this movement influences your mesh. If the mesh deforms while doing that, this is a check.

Answer (score 0):

maybe the problem is you has not apply rotation and scale of your mesh.

before skinning make sure pressing "Ctrl A" and select rotation and scale

Comment: Same problem, this solution doesnt change anything :s